# Recognize operating system in Prolog

Tags: operating-system, prolog

Is there anyway to find out what operating system currently being used through prolog please?

Thanks,
L

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) you can examine *execution environment*  including operating system by means of the  [current_prolog_flag](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=current_prolog_flag%2f2) predicate

Try:

```
?- current_prolog_flag(arch, Arch).
?- current_prolog_flag(unix, U).
?- current_prolog_flag(windows, W).
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the answer but I would advise that you try to use a foreign language extension like C. The documentation for SWI-Prolog C library is [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/clib.html)